# One Spritesheet to animate multiples sprites. Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I have one spritesheet for my player. The spritesheet contains the base outfit, a hat (with no outfit just the hat) and a sword (just the sword). So what I want is stack all of them to have a outfit + hat + sword or maybe just outfit + sword, etc.. But what I have now is just the animations for the base outfit that works ok they are:

```
createAnimations() {

  /**
   * Outfit animatioons unmount
   */
  this.anims.create({
    key: 'up',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('male_pirate', {
      frames: [0, 48, 92, 130, 168, 205,232, 258, 278]
    }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
  });

  this.anims.create({
    key: 'right',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('male_pirate', {
      frames: [2, 50, 94, 132, 170, 207, 234, 260, 280]
    }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
  });
  this.anims.create({
    key: 'down',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('male_pirate', {
      frames: [4, 52, 96, 134, 172, 209, 236, 262, 282]
    }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
  });
  
  this.anims.create({
    key: 'left',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('male_pirate', {
      frames: [6, 54, 98, 136, 174, 211, 238, 264, 284]
    }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
  });


  /**
   * Addon 1 animations.
   */
}
```

I import the spritesheet like:

```
    this.load.spritesheet('male_pirate', 'assets/outfits/descarga64.png', {
      frameWidth: 64,
      frameHeight: 64
    });
```

and I create the player:

```
 this.player = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'male_pirate', 0);
 this.container = this.add.container(playerInfo.x, playerInfo.y);
 this.container.setSize(32, 32);
 this.physics.world.enable(this.container);
 this.container.add(this.player);
```

Is it possible to create multiples sprites with the same spritesheet and use diferent frames for each sprite when animating?

Because when I do

```
  this.anims.create({
    key: 'up',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('male_pirate', {
      frames: [0, 48, 92, 130, 168, 205,232, 258, 278]
    }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
  });
```

I'm animating the spritesheet "male_pirate" with the frames [0, 48, 92, 130, 168, 205,232, 258, 278].

But what I want is when the key up is pressed animate the "sprite player" with the frames [0, 48, 92, 130, 168, 205,232, 258, 278] and the "sprite sword" with the frames [12, 60, 500, ...] and the "sprite hat" with the frames [15,28,..]

I could do it by using different spritesheets for the outfit, and the sword but I would like to avoid the work of re-organize the spritesheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you want dynamic "sprites" / GameObjects I would recommend to do it with Spine (look [at this offical example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/spine/basic-spineboy), *or checkout this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sq6mnix8eAg&t=1s) for some "basic" infos about spine/bones*).

But If you have the images already, and want a quick solution. I say generate the new sprites in game, since animating multiple sprites one ontop of the other could cause animation sync problems.

Checkout [this post](https://phaser.discourse.group/t/is-there-a-way-to-combine-multiple-part-images-into-one-object/12579/4?u=akumagamo) on the phaser discourse, it explains how you can paint multiple images in phaser together an create like this a "new Sprite", but still using the same animation.
*(At the bottom of the thread there is even a small codepen showing some working code)*

> *If animation glitches are okay for you game, you simply create animations for each sprite/outfit combination, adn just play them one ontop of the other, depending of the current outfit*